# Awaitility.await().atMost(...) causes program to exit if time out interval expires?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency

This question regards com.jayway.awaitility.Awaitility.

I just tried Awaitility.await() and it seems to have some odd behavior.
In the test method below if I comment out testWithFuture() and enable 
testWithAwaitility(),  I never  see the message  "end " printed out.
I see 'start ', then the program just exits, and the second
print statement never seems to be reached.

So as a work around I decided to use Settable{Future}..  If anyone else has the same issue then maybe the work-around I provide will be useful.. Even better would be to get a nice answer ;^)      !  thanks in advance  / chris

THE CODE:

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import static com.jayway.awaitility.Awaitility.await;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

public class AwaitTest {
    static volatile boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        testWithFuture();
        //testWithAwaitility();
    }

    private static void testWithAwaitility() {
        System.out.println("start " + new Date());
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                done = true;
            }

        }).start();


        await().atMost(2, SECONDS).until(new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                return done;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("end " + new Date());   // NEVER Reached. i wonder why?

    }

    // This does what I want.
    //
    private static void testWithFuture() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        System.out.println("start testWithFuture");

        final SettableFuture future = SettableFuture. create();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
                future.set("Hello");
            }

        }).start();

        String result = future.get(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (! result.equals("Hello")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("not equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("got Hello");

        }
    }
 }
```

CORRECTED CODE ->

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import static com.jayway.awaitility.Awaitility.await;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

public class Sample {
    static volatile boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testWithAwaitility();
    }

    private static void testWithAwaitility() {
        System.out.println("start " + new Date());
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                done = true;
            }

        }).start();


        try {
            await().atMost(2, SECONDS).until(new Callable() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                    return done;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAILED");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("end " + new Date());   // REACHED this statement after correction
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/awaitility/wiki/Usage), `await()` throws a `TimeoutException` if the timeout is reached and the condition is not true, so your method ends at this point because the exception is propagated up through the stack. This explains the behavior. You should see a stacktrace, however.

If you want to continue executing code afterwards, it seems you would need to catch this exception.

Comment: Catching the exception works.   I edited the original post with the correction you suggested. thank you.